# How to find the number of gaps between words in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

Given an NSString containing a sentence I would like to determine the number of gaps between the words.

I could use something like [[theString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].

But that would only work if each gap is a single space character, there could be multiple.

Comment: What is your actual end goal?

Comment: You know, you could just write a loop to iterate through the string and count what you want to count.  In general this will be faster than other approaches, since it doesn't require the creation of new objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSRegularExpression, like:

```
NSString *test = @"The quick        brown fox  jumped over    the lazy dog";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\s+" options:0 error:NULL];
NSUInteger num = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, test.length)];
NSLog(@"num: %lu", num);
```

The regular expression "\s+" matches one or more whitespace characters (it's written here with an extra "\" because we need a literal backslash in the NSString).  `numberOfMatchesInString:options:range:` counts each run of one or more whitespace characters as a match, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `componentsSeparatedByString` - if you filter afterwards to ignore the empty strings:

```
NSString *theString = @"HI     this   is a    test";
NSArray *arr = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
arr = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *b) {
    return [(NSString*)evaluatedObject length] > 0;
}]];

NSLog(@"number of words: %lu", arr.count);
NSLog(@"number of gaps: %lu", arr.count - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the 'coolest' way, but this might be the fastest and cleanest

```
NSArray *components= [theString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"gaps: %f", components.count - 1);
```

Comment: @rmaddy misunderstood the question. Funnily OP almost had the answer himself. I will update my solution